# What’s the quickest way to get diamonds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanted to know, what’s the quickest way to get diamonds? I want to start a survival world, but I want to be able to get diamonds quickly. Please share the **quickest** ways you found!

Comment: Please narrow your question down to a specific Minecraft version. The answer may very based on the version you’re playing

Comment: Ok, I narrowed it down to Bedrock Edition, because that’s what I’m playing on

Comment: Honestly the quickest way is to get lucky. Some seeds will have villages with diamonds in right by spawn so you don't even have to go mining. If you aren't on such a seed then grab your pickaxes and get mining at Y=11. There's not really a definitive answer to this for the general case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most efficient Minecraft mining strategy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/whats-the-most-efficient-minecraft-mining-strategy)

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient mining strategy would be to go down to y-11 and do branch mining. Here is a detailed list of diamond-mining methods, ranging from early-game to late-game.

### Simple Branch Mining (Beginner)

This method is for beginners. (just started a new world)

**Advantages**

- Very thorough
- No risk of lava at head height
- Many other useful resources uncovered

**Disadvantages**

- Very resource-intensive
- Many trips may be needed to deposit resources

**Resources needed**

- A few stone pickaxes
- 1-2 iron pickaxes
- A few stacks of torches

**Optional resources**

- A stack of scaffolding blocks (ie cobblestone)
- A water bucket

**Steps to do it**

1. Mine a hole or staircase down to y-11.
2. Create a 2x2 tunnel in one direction.
3. Create small 1x2 indentations on both sides, skipping 2 blocks at a time. It should look like this:

```
Key: W = Wall, S = Space, ... = continue pattern
      ......
      W S S W
    W W S S W W
... S S S S S S ...
    W W S S W W
      W S S W
       .....
```

4. Mine the indentations forward until you are satisfied.

**Yields**

- 9 diamonds per hour

### Simple Branch Mining (Advanced)

This method is the same as the above mentioned method, but for mid to late-game players.

**Resources needed**

- Several diamond/netherite pickaxes (preferably enchanted with Unbreaking 3, Efficiency 5, Mending)
- A few stacks of torches

**Optional resources**

- A water bucket
- A Haste II beacon
- Pickaxes enchanted with Silk Touch
- An XP farm readily available nearby to repair tools
- A diamond/netherite shovel
- A few shulker boxes to store materials

### Field Mining

This method removes all blocks at a y-level very quickly

**Advantages**

- **Very** thorough
- No risk of lava at head height
- Easy to navigate and scout
- Covers a large area

**Disadvantages**

- Resource-intensive
- Low blocks mined to blocks uncovered ratio

**Resources needed**

- Several diamond/netherite pickaxes (preferably enchanted with Unbreaking 3, Efficiency 5, Mending)
- A few stacks of torches

**Optional resources**

- A water bucket
- A Haste II beacon
- Pickaxes enchanted with Silk Touch
- An XP farm readily available nearby to repair tools
- A diamond/netherite shovel
- A few shulker boxes to store materials

**How to do it**

1. Mine down to y-11.
2. Start mining all around in circles where you are.
3. Expand the circle that you made.
4. Repeat step 3 until you are satisfied.

**Yields**

- 8 diamonds per hour

### TNT Mining

This method is fun to watch.

**Advantages**

- Very satisfying to watch
- Many blocks uncovered

**Disadvantages**

- Very resource-intensive
- You may blow yourself up
- Some diamond ores may be destroyed upon explosion
- Much preparations are needed

**Resources needed**

- A few stacks of TNT
- A few iron or better pickaxes
- Flint and steel **OR** a Flame bow

**Optional resources**

- A water bucket
- Blast protection armor

**How to do it**

1. Dig out an area where you want to blow things up.
2. Place the TNT in this grid arrangement:

```
Key: T = TNT, S = Space, ... = Continue this pattern
                   ...
... T S S T S S T S S T S S T S S T S S T ...
... T S S T S S T S S T S S T S S T S S T ...
                   ...
```

3. With the bow or flint and steel, ignite a TNT.
4. Wait for all TNT to explode.
5. Ignite all remaining TNT
6. Collect resources uncovered.

**Yields**

- ~0.4 diamond per 10 TNT

If you want a detailed list of methods for netherite, check out [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374667/what-is-the-best-way-to-mine-netherite). If you have any other methods you would like to inquire about, comment down below. I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, I shall try that then. I haven't been here in a while, so forgive me for being 2 months late